# question about proof that $f$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I have a question about the solution to this question 
[Is the function $ f(x,y)=xy/(x^{2}+y^{2})$ where f(0,0) is defined to be 0 continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518357/is-the-function-fx-y-xy-x2y2-where-f0-0-is-defined-to-be-0-conti)

If I want to prove that $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$, it should be enough to realize that for example $f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{2}$, or do I have to determine the limit if I come from an other direction to $(0,0)$ too? If yes, why?

Answer (score 3):

Your observation about $f(\frac1n,\frac1n)$ suffices (as $(\frac1m,\frac1n)\to (0,0)$) to show that this $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. However, the advantage of also trying another direction is that one sees that even with a different definition of $f$ at the point $(0,0)$ (for example, $f(0,0)=\frac12$), we cannot make it continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=x$, then $f={1\over 2}$, if $y=2x$,then $f={2\over 5}$, so when $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ in different directions, limit different, that means discontinuous.