# How can I prove this limit doesn't exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Right now, I'm doing a question:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2 +y^2}$$

I know the limit doesn't exist, but I can't figure out how to prove it. I tried putting $x=1$, and getting $0/y^2$, and put $y=0$, got $0/(x^2-2x+1)$, but I don't think that does it.

(edit: this is not a duplicate; I'm having a hard time getting good explanations, hence why I asked)

Comment: Set $z=x-1$. Then this is the same as showing that the limit $\lim_{(z,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{zy}{z^2+y^2}$ does not exist. Then this is a very common example. See, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518357/is-the-function-fx-y-xy-x2y2-where-f0-0-is-defined-to-be-0-conti

Comment: Parametrize lines a varying slope through $(1,0)$ then restrict the function to the lines to get one variable limits. Evaluate and see the limit depends on the slope of the line, hence it doesn't tend towards a single value, so it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Along the path $y=x-1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}&=\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{(x-1)^2}{2(x-1)^2}\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$

Along the path $y=0$, we have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}=0$$

Comment: how did you chose to make y=x-1 instead of y=0 (because isn't y going to zero?)

Comment: Indeed, $y\to 0$. Inasmuch as $x\to 1$, then $y=x-1\to 0$

Comment: oh, so you just related the values of x and y, because y is 1 less than x, hence y=x-1?

Comment: Not quite.  I merely found two paths on which the limit differs.  Another way to see this is to let $x=1+r\cos(\phi)$ and $y=r\sin(\phi)$.  Then, $$\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}=\frac12\sin(2\phi)$$

Comment: I have a test Friday, so would whats in the previous comment have worked, and could it work in other problems (like limit as x,y approach 2, 4) of some function?

Comment: Krissy, the limit, if it exists, must be independent of the path taken.  Here, we begin in a some deleted neighborhood of $(1,0)$ and approach $(1,0)$.  Note that if we move along the line $y=x-1$, the limit is $1/2$.  If we move along the line $y=0$, the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take la sequence of points $P_n=(1\pm \frac 1n,\frac 1n)$. You have $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(1\pm \frac 1n)\frac 1n-\frac 1n}{(\pm\frac 1n)^2+((\frac 1n)^2}=\pm \frac 12$$ These two distinct limits say that the limit doesn't exist.