# Multivariable Limit - Does it exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I know that the limit below

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}$ $\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$

does not exist. However, I haven't found a path that is not equal to 0. I have tried: $y=mx$, $x=cy^2$,$y=0$, and $x=0$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: replace $x$ by $t+1$ and try the limit as $(t,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

Comment: We cannot use the paths $y=mx$ and $x=0$ as they do not pass through the point $(1,0)$.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)}\frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1800138/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7B(x%2Cy)%5Cto(1%2C0)%7D%5Cfrac%7Bxy-y%7D%7B(x-1)%5E2%2By%5E2%7D%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$ \frac{xy - y}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} = \frac{(x-1) y}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}
$$
so we can evaluate the limit
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}
$$
instead.

Observe that using polar coordinates,
$$ \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{r^2}
$$
so....

Answer (score 1):

Try paths $ (x,y) = (1+t,t)$ or $(1-t,t)$
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{t\to 0}f(1 \pm t,t)$$

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{xy-y}{(x-1)^2+y^2} = \lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac{(1 \pm t)t - t}{t^2 + t^2} = \pm \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Neither  limit equals zero.